# PHP: escapeshellarg() is not escaping "\t"

Tags: php, shell

What i want to do is execute an application and pass a file path as a parameter. Here is my code:

```
$path = "\\SERVER-1\Source\temp\test\Letters\New Letter.doc"
shell_exec("pdfgenerator.exe ".escapeshellarg ( $path));
```

The problematic part here is `$path`. Basically i want to be able to handle all kinds of file path strings including those with spaces in names etc etc.

In this particular case, i have found that  `escapeshellarg()` is not escaping the "\" in `\temp` and causing the "t" to be interpeted as a tab character. Any ideas how i can get this to pass properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't `escapeshellarg()`'s problem. The `\t` is being parsed as a tab (*0x09*) by the PHP parser before it's reached `escapeshellarg()`. This is because you're placing the string inside of double quotes, which causes PHP to do further complex interpolation on your string. [See the manual for more details on differences between single and double quote strings](http://php.net/language.types.string).

Try it with single quotes and see the difference for yourself.

```
$string1 = "\\SERVER-1\Source\temp\test\Letters\New Letter.doc";
$string2 = '\\SERVER-1\Source\temp\test\Letters\New Letter.doc';
var_dump($string1, $string2, escapeshellarg($string1), escapeshellarg($string2));
```

Output should be...

```
string(47) "\SERVER-1\Source    emp est\Letters\New Letter.doc"
string(49) "\SERVER-1\Source\temp\test\Letters\New Letter.doc"
string(49) "'\SERVER-1\Source   emp est\Letters\New Letter.doc'"
string(51) "'\SERVER-1\Source\temp\test\Letters\New Letter.doc'"
```

Answer (score 1):

use single quotes instead of double ones and you should be fine

```
<?php

$path = '\\SERVER-1\Source\temp\test\Letters\New Letter.doc';

print escapeshellarg($path);
// will output "\SERVER-1\Source\temp\test\Letters\New Letter.doc"

shell_exec("pdfgenerator.exe ".escapeshellarg ( $path));
```